# providing created_at and updated_at in mass insert for rails with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm doing [a mass insert](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) a la @chris-heald. If you're interacting with the database directly using raw SQL, do you need to provide the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields yourself or will you get that for free from postgres? I'm unclear whether it's Rails or postgres that does the automagical generation here.

Comment: Do you have defaults set for created_at, updated_at in your schema?  If not and you're doing raw SQL inserts you'll need to set created_at and updated_at to now()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActiveRecord sets the `updated_at` and `created_at` values by itself, it doesn't set up the database to supply those values.

If you're doing a bulk insert through SQL then you have some options:

1. Assign them manually by using `Time.now.utc.iso8601` to build the necessary strings. If you need greater precision in your timestamps then you can use `strftime` instead of `iso8601` to build the strings.
2. Let the database do it by setting default values for those two columns. You could say:

   ```
   alter table your_table alter column created_at set default now();
   alter table your_table alter column created_at set default now();
   ```

   to add the defaults, then do your bulk import, and then get rid of the defaults using:

   ```
   alter table your_table alter column created_at drop default;
   alter table your_table alter column created_at drop default;
   ```

   You'd use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` to send those ALTER TABLEs into your database if you're doing all this from within Rails.